# How do I create a table in mySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ddl, create-table

Below in the SQL I wrote in mySQL workbench it creates the database fine but will not create the table to hold my products.

```
DROP DATABASE bamazon_db;
CREATE DATABASE bamazon_db;
USE bamazon_db;
CREATE TABLE products (
item_id(10) AUTO INCREMENT,
product_name,
price,
stock_quantity,
);
```

Comment: Why You write sql query when MySQL Workbench has forms for it? About query: You've to define field types since db does not understand what kind of field You want to create.

Comment: You can also drop `USE bamazon_db;` when you fully qualified the table name with a database name like so `CREATE TABLE  bamazon_db.products (...)` that also works with SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE the same way.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the column types:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    item_id INT AUTO INCREMENT,
    product_name VARCHAR(100),
    price INT,
    stock_quantity INT
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two major problems with your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

1. None of your columns have types. You must declare a type for each column in the table, e.g. `price DECIMAL(5,2)`.
2. You have misspelled `AUTO_INCREMENT` as `AUTO INCREMENT`.